# understanding 2 shell functions

Tags: linux, function, shell

Can someone enlighten me as to how the following 2 functions work? i couldn't get my head around the eval part. 
these code snippets come from a system script on Openwrt.Thank you

```
list_contains() {
        local var="$1"
        local str="$2"
        local val

       eval "val=\" \${$var} \""
    [ "${val%% $str *}" != "$val" ]
}


append() {
        local var="$1"
        local value="$2"
        local sep="${3:- }"

        eval "export ${NO_EXPORT:+-n} -- \"$var=\${$var:+\${$var}\${value:+\$sep}}\$value\""
}
```

Comment: `man bash` has all the answers. `set -xv` can also help.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these functions use shell variable substitutions.

sh$ variable=prefixandsuffix
   sh$ echo "${variable#prefix}"
   andsuffix
   sh$ echo "${variable%suffix}"
   prefixand

The `%%` and `##` variants substitute the longest possible match, whereas the functions above will replace the shortest possible match.

So `${val%% $str *}` attempts to remove a suffix containing `$str` surrounded by whitespace, followed by anything.  If there is no match, nothing is removed, so `${val%% $str *}` is equal to `$val`.

By the by, I find this rather cumbersome.  I would write this function instead simply as

```
case " $val " in *" $str "*) true;; *) false;; esac
```

Similarly, the `append` function attempts to append a value to a list in a rather roundabout way.  This function uses default values.

```
sh$ echo "${variable:-value_if_unset}"
prefixandsuffix
sh$ echo "${another:-value_if_unset}"
value_if_unset
sh$ echo "${variable:+foo}"
foo
sh$ echo "x${another:+foo}"
x
```

The purpose of the complex `eval` here is to just set the variable to its new value if it was not set before, and otherwise set it to the old value followed by the separator and the new value to append.

Again, it seems that this would be simpler written just

```
variable="${variable}${variable:+ }newvalue"
```

inline, instead of resorting to a fairly complex function.